# Syntax error with 'swagger-render' on mac os

Tags: python, swagger

I've installed `swagger-render` through `pip` according to installation instructions from this website:

- https://pypi.org/project/swagger-render/

But when I'm trying to launch it, I see weird syntax error. Could somebody, please, explain and help to resolve this issue?

#### Python version

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.15
```

#### Pip version

```
$ pip --version
pip 10.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

#### Error message

```
$ swagger-render swagger.yaml -o index.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/swagger-render", line 7, in <module>
    from swagger_render.__main__ import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/swagger_render/__main__.py", line 49
    def all_of(*items, root=None):
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: keyword parameters should precede optional argument parameters; that's why the syntax error.

Comment: @mshsayem So this is the bug in `swagger-render` library? I've installed with `pip install swagger-render` version that contains syntax errors?

Comment: The syntax is correct for Python 3+, but invalid for 2.x

Comment: @mshsayem Thanks a lot! This resolves my issue. I just need to use `python3`.